# How to print ASCII instead of integer in C?

Tags: c

Let's say I have the integer 89, how can I print out the ASCII value of 89 which is Y instead of just printing out the number 89?

Comment: `printf("%c",value)`

Comment: May I suggest to read the comp.lang.c FAQ at http://c-faq.com/ It has a plenty of answers for such basic questions, and the more difficult ones.

Comment: @Arctic_Skill: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have an integer `int value = 89;` you can

- use `printf("%c", value);` instead of `printf("%d", value);`.
- or simply `putchar(value);`

Note however that `Y` is not the ASCII value of `89`. It is the other way around: character `Y` has an ASCII value of `89`.  The C language supports different character sets besides ASCII, so `'Y'` might not necessarily have the value `89`, indeed its value is `232` on IBM Mainframes that still use the EBCDIC character set.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `c` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%c\n", (char) 89);
```

or as pointed out by *[chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957874/how-to-print-ascii-instead-of-integer-in-c/40957882#comment69124978_40957882), just simply:

```
printf("%c\n", 89);
```

or with context:

```
char c = 89;  /* or int c = 89; */

printf("%hhd is '%c'.\n", c, c);
```

---

[Referencing the C11 Standard (draft)](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> [...]
>
> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> [...]
>
> c
>
> [...] the `int` argument is converted to an
>   `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

Comment: The `(char)` cast is not necessary. The argument for `%c` is an `int` and its value is converted to `unsigned char` by `printf` internally.

Comment: @chqrlie, but it makes the intent clear. This isn't a mistake in formatting. Plus it may prevent certain popular compilers from complaining when they validate the format string.

Comment: @StoryTeller:  Which compiler would complain about `printf("%c\n", 89);`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Which popular compiler complains about it without the cast?

Comment: @chqrlie, I got a warning from gcc once. But it seems to have since been fixed (was a false positive in my case)

Comment: @StoryTeller: `gcc` 4.7.2 definitely no longer complains about this. But neither `gcc` not `clang` complain about `printf("%c\n", 8989);` which is more questionable.

Comment: @chqrlie, your point being? I already retracted my statement. GCC doesn't complain about this example.

Comment: @StoryTeller: my point being that there are cases where it would seem useful for the compiler to complain about an `int` argument for `%c`. No criticism, just a positive remark.

Comment: @chqrlie, apologies. Had some unpleasant run-ins on SO recently. I agree that the diagnostic can be a whole lot better than it is today (or was back when I remember misfiring). Should be easy with literals, anyway.